# Accessing same macro in C, from different files representing different values

Tags: c, file, macros, header, embedded

I have two different header files with same macros in both, representing some equations. For eg; I have F1 in function1.h and also in function2.h, but both of these represent two different equations. In some cases I will need to use F1 from function1.h, while in some other case i will need F1 from function2.h. How could i possibly implement this logic in C.

```
//function1.h
#define F1 x+10
#define F2 x*10
//function2.h
#define F1 x+210
#define F2 x*99

//main.c
#include "function1.h"
#include "function2.h"

int x = 10;

if(..something..)
return(F1)       //from function1.h
if(..something..else..)
return(F1)       //from function2.h
```

//anyway to implement this logic without ambiguity

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You'll need to use different labels if you wish to do this. Or you could add an argument: #define F1(A) x + A. To use for case 1: F1(10) and in your second case: F1(210). You only need one definition of F1 then. Same kind of thing for F2.

Comment: @MichaelWalz pls check the update

Comment: The approach seems completely wrong to me. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve ? Please read about the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Side note: unrelated to your problem: if you have `#define F2 x*99` and further you have `a = F2(1 + 1)`, what would the value of `a` be then ?

Comment: As a rule of thumb: use functions instead of macros and all your problems will go away.

Comment: Lundin I take your point but I think it is important to add that a function call comes with an overhead (inline functions are an option but messy). In such instances macros are the only way of keeping code compact while maintaining performance.

Answer (score 0):

If they're doing different things they should be named differently (and they are if they're "shorthand" for different equations as you suggest). The precompiler operations may be doing something you're not expecting. So for example, the second header file, if listed in the same source file as the first, may actually have F1 replaced by the aliased code for the same macro name in the first. This would likely give you a compilation error though.

Remember the precompiler is just replacing the macro label with the code that is being "aliased" by the macro label. This is then the source code that is compiled. You probably know this but some folk think macros are some type of function nomenclature.

```
#define F1 x+10
#define F2 x*10
//function2.h
#define F1 x+210
#define F2 x*99
```

Change to:

```
#define F1(A) x+A
#define F2(A) x*A
```

You don't need two different macros in each case. You shouldn't be doing what you're currently doing - see previous paragraph.

To use:

```
return(F1(10));
```

or

```
return(F1(210));
```

Depending on the case.

Comment: thankyou.
but the scenario is little different. the header files are some kind of standard representing  some complex equations. and the cant be touched.

Comment: @Mahi you should put that information into your question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanx Michael for your help! Really appreciate it.! "claps"

Comment: @Mahi if you have two macros the with the same label (name) in two different header files you cannot include those header files and expect the precompiler to give them some special treatment. You'll have to rename one set if you're going to use both header files in the same source file. What you're asking for cannot be done without changing the name of at least two macros in one of the header files or redefining the macro. There is no way around this issue as you have presented it. I cannot think of any combination here of #ifndef and #define that will make things work as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that would be the short answer. I suspect that the long answer will be the same, but here goes.

As they are macros, it is possible to undefine them. As these are pre-existing headers, they are likely to have additional clashing definitions - so you would have to undefine quite a bit.

That code would look like this

```
#include "function1.h"
int my_function1_f1(int x)
{
    return F1(x);
}
#undef F1
// You would probably have to undefine a lot more here

#include "function2.h"
int my_function2_f1(int x)
{
    return F1(x);
}
#undef F2 // Do this for neatness
```

You can then call the "right" version of F1 by using either my_function1_f1(), or my_function2_f1().

A better answer would be to create additional source files, one to access the functions in function1.h and the other to access those from function2.h.

With this you can happily include both of your new headers as the clashing function1.h would only be included in myfunction1.c and function2.h would only be included in myfunction2.c.